# Ubuntu always change user

Tags: su

I have no idea what is the topic of my problem.

I have to change the user using `su user` when accessing the server with `ssh user@server`

The initial terminal shows just `>` without a user name (i.e., `user@server >`) before the change user (i.e., `su user`)

The process is so bothering me. Please note the reason, answer.

Thanks

Comment: What does `id -un` show when you initially log in on the remote machine. What shell is being used and what does `echo "$-"` output? My thinking is that you've logged in as the correct user, but that one of the shell's initialization files (that sets the prompt) just isn't executed.

Comment: The shell prompt is very customizable. Maybe the server administrator has changed the default prompt to `>` for some reason: perhaps an attempt to increase security by making the system more obscure? A need to satisfy some contract or security audit requirement to minimize the amount of information displayed? Personal preference? The only way to know the fundamental reason would be to ask the server administrator about it.

Comment: @Kusalananda The remote machine shows the _user_ name when `id -un`. And the `echo "$-"` shows _smi_

Comment: Ok, so you just have the wrong prompt, not the wrong user account. Is the `PS1` variable (the primary prompt) set in `~/.bashrc` or in `~/.bash_profile` on the remote system (assuming you're using the `bash` shell)?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, there is in `~/.bashrc` with the following:

`if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
`